# set or update profile picture using fbconnect facebook?

Tags: facebook, profile, image, fbconnect

i have a image and i want to set this image as the users profile image. i came to know that we cannot upload directly to "Profile pictures" so i uploaded it in some other album and now i want to set this image as its profile pic ???
any idea how can i do that using fbconnect ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

well i guess this is not possible...

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload
3rd paragraph says:
You can upload to a specific user's album by calling photos.getAlbums. However, you cannot upload to a user's profile picture album.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my answer in this thread: [how to set a facebook profile picture using the graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api/5431751#5431751)

You can't set the profile picture, but you can upload it to an album, and then send the user to the "make profile picture"-page for that picture.

Comment: well, I dont think its a good solution. Why ? Because still you are asking a user to perform some action. Once the user has selected some image it should be uploaded in any album or any particular then you yourself programmatically should be able to set it as a profile picture. Why I am saying that because I am trying to achieve the same task in iPhone and your solution will make an extra edge/step. and will involve manual steps to do so.

Comment: @yunas: yes, I agree, but this is kind of a walkaround, since the API at the moment (or at least last time I checked) dont allow you to update the profile image of a user directly.