# how to set a facebook profile picture using the graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to change the user's profile picture using the graph api?

I know you can't with the rest api ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995397/set-or-update-profile-picture-using-fbconnect-facebook)), but I could not find anything in the new graph api.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I set a users profile image using the Facebook API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648859/can-i-set-a-users-profile-image-using-the-facebook-api)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Upload the picture to an existing album (or create a new one) using the Graph API.
Will look something like this:

```php
  $args = array('message' => 'Caption');
  $args['image'] = '@' . realpath("the_image.png");

  try {
    $data = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $args);
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($e);
    print "</pre>";
  }
```

Then get the uploaded image via the Graph API and redirect to the image's link, add `&makeprofile=1` to the querystring. The user will now be redirected to the profile image cropping page:

```php
try {
  $pictue = $facebook->api('/'.$data['id']);
  header("Location: ".$pictue['link']."&makeprofile=1");
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  print "<pre>";
  print_r($e);
  print "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Facebook doesn´t mind us doing this? No policy violation?

Comment: No, not that I know of. I've used it in a live app, and there where no problems there.

Comment: @Mattias I don't expect this to be a violation of policy, because you're not setting the profile image yourself. It only pops up a dialog in which the user is allowed to do so and he can choose not to.

Comment: this isn't working. I am trying using graph api explorer with url
https://graph.facebook.com/albumid/photos
Fields :-

message, url, makeprofile

What is it am i doing wrong ?

Comment: How to get album_uid

Comment: Help, I don't achieve to get the picture link

Comment: @fredrik, salih kallai has a good question: how do you get the `album_id`?

Comment: @AlexisWilke I haven't used the facebook apis in many years, but  a get on /me/albums seems to get you the ids of the albums (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums&version=v2.7)

Comment: @fredrik, indeed, I got them that way and you can then query that album (`/<album-id>`) for its type and know whether it is the user profile pictures or not.

Comment: Sadly the 'makeprofile=1' trick doesn't seem to work anymore.  It *is* the URL that facebook uses, but it only works if you click on it from the theater view.

Comment: Considering that this method requires eventual user confirmation, isn't https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309984/9731176 a more concise replacement for the last section?

Comment: @DavidLjungMadisonStellar, that probably just means that someone needs to see what the website sends OTA using a packet sniffer, right? I can't imagine it's anything inherently server-side.

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 8):

PicBadges application (no longer available) is doing this job clearly. Just take a look at their app. Its pretty clear how they have implemented.

They are not directly uploading pictures to "Profile Pictures" album. Instead, they are uploading as usual to their auto generated album (on their app name) and then selecting the pic as "profile pic". However, this method involves redirection of users to page where they need to *crop* it before getting done.

Interesting implementation to note!

Comment: I've edited the answer to remove the url, which now leads to an ad page.

Answer (score 5):

You can upload to the user's Profile Picture album using the Graph API but it appears that you cannot update the /me/picture value to set the users current profile image to the image you've uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

**User Picture:** *Graph API Version v6.0*

**Reading**

You can get the pictue with the endpoint `/{user-id}/picture`

**Creating**

You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

**Updating**

You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

**Deleting**

You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I've managed to upload a profile picture using this endpoint.

This [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/#Creating) provides information about how to upload a profile picture

```js
        private async uploadProfilePhoto(pageId:string, accessToken: string, photoUrl: string){
            let url = FACEBOOK_API_URL + `${pageId}/picture`+ 
                `?access_token=${accessToken}`+
                `&picture=${photoUrl}`;
            let response = null;

            try {
             response = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url:  url,
            }); 
            } catch (err) {
                /**  Here this error occures but the profile image is still uploaded. 
                 * {message: 'Unsupported post request.', type: 'GraphMethodException', code: 100, fbtrace_id: 'AGhsadasdaiqyf_YHJaztdasdadG7'
                 */           
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Then to get the id of the profile picture in case you need it you can perform a get request on this endpoint.

```js
const FACEBOOK_API_URL ='https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/'
let url = FACEBOOK_API_URL + `${pageId}/photos`+
            `?access_token=${accessToken}` +
            `&fields=picture`;
```