# How to trigger "Set as profile picture" dialog (in facebook sdk/fbml)?

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-graph-api

in my last question I've asked how to set (write) a "generated" picture as profile picture in facebook. The answer was 'not possible'.

Now I need to know: But **how do I write my code to get a button "Set this picture as profile picture", which triggers me the core function from facebook?**

I have seen this so many times in user apps, but I don't finde anything about it in the API.

Comment: If the question is unclear please let me know - thanks.

Comment: Do't post your last question...Just post your new question..Then no confusion..Any way its an interesting question(NEW QUESTION!!) Juat check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api

Comment: @Damodaran he made sure to include his last question to prevent people from misinterpreting his new question. I believe this brings more clarity as to his intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my answer in this thread: [how to set a facebook profile picture using the graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api/5431751#5431751)