# How to set uploaded photo as profile picture

Tags: facebook, cakephp, profile

I've been trying this for the past few days but it seems I'm missing something: Well, I'm able to upload a photo to a users profile with the following code (I'm using cakephp with [Nick Baker's](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin) facebook plugin):

```
$Fb = new FB();
      FB::setFileUploadSupport(true);
   $token = FB::getAccessToken();

//upload photo
$file= IMAGES.'badge.png';

$attachment = array(
    'access_token'=> $token,
    'name' => 'Album name',
    'source' => '@'.$file
                );
    $fb_photo = FB::api('/me/photos','POST', $attachment);
```

I am able to upload the photo to a new album and I would like to redirect the user to set the uploaded photo as their facebook profile profile. I followed [an answer posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api/5431751#5431751) but it appears i'm still missing something. I'm able to get the uploaded photo id using `$fb_photo['id']` but i'm not able to get the photo link (i tried `$fb_photo['link']` as suggested in a comment but it returns NULL). What am I doing wrong, or what I should I do to achieve a successful redirect? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The callback to posting a photo is just the Photo ID, you also need to then request the photo's full details back from the API,

so after

```
$fb_photo = FB::api('/me/photos','POST', $attachment);
```

You need to do something like

```
$fb_photo_details = FB::api('/'.$fb_photo);
$link = $fb_photo_details['link'];
```