# Publish Facebook user's profile picture programmatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to publish user's profile picture programmatically using `Graph API` ?

What I need is to post selected image to the Facebook API and set it as a default avatar.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No dear, its not possible.all you can do is to fetch it from FB but cant set it.its out of facebook doc.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible......................................

Comment: Umh, how's that not an answer? "No, it is not possible." certainly is one possible answer to the question of "Is it possible?". There are some things that are not possible, after all...

Comment: @Franci Penov: seems like I've missed the "dear" keyword to be checked, lol

Comment: @Rikesh: how would **you** answer?