# using byte to store image

Tags: c#, image, facebook, byte

```
 using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
 {
   using (Stream s = wc.OpenRead("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userid + "/picture?type=normal"))
     {
       using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s))
           {
              ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
              Byte[] bytes1 = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmp,typeof(byte[]));
              String prof = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes1);
                        facebookuser.profilepic = prof;
            }
      }
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profilepic", Encoding.Default.GetBytes(_profilepic));
```

Hi i am trying to store facebook profile picture and display but it seems that the byte I store is wrong because after using this code to store there is no image display. May I know is there any errors when converting to byte?

Comment: If the intention is convert the image to bytes using `ImageConverter`, then convert to `base64` then there is nothing wrong with your code. However i am not sure what `facebookuser.profilepi` is and what all this is about `Encoding.Default.GetBytes(_profilepic)` also, i would double check the bmp by saving it somewhere and checking it

Comment: [did you see this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953087/publish-facebook-users-profile-picture-programmatically)