# Setting an image from ios OR Android app as Facebook Profile Picture (Using Facebook API)

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can we set an image from an iOS OR Android app  as Facebook Profile Picture.Using Facebook API If possible then how?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook doesn't appear to provide an API to change the profile picture. You could always try to replicate what some Web apps are doing: upload the image and then try to guide to user to tap the "make Profile picture" button (by showing UIWebView and pointing it to the relevant page).

See this question (not iOS or Android specific):

[how to set a facebook profile picture using the graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can get your hands on the image, then upload it to your account or page as profile picture, it should do the trick. I can help you resize the image, if you'd like. Just tell me the app you want the image from.

Comment: Thanks Toby. We can share images (on Wall). Can you tell me a specific way to set an image directly as Profile Pic..

Comment: Through an iOS device or computer?

Comment: through iOS device...

Comment: If it's on iOS devices, I can help you right now, but if it is on the computer, you'll have to wait until I get home from work. I can't really go on Facebook here, you know... In the meantime, could you please tell me the name of the app you'd like the image from?

Comment: Toby I am developing an iOS app. user can generate different images within the app. How can user set an image generated in the app as his/her facebook profile pic...

Comment: Alright, on iOS device, upload an image to your page, then view that image. On the left hand bottom corner, you'll see some icons. One of them looks like three dots. Tap those dots, and you'll get to choose from 4 options. If your language preferences are set to "English", it'll say something like "Set this picture as profile photo".

Comment: Oh, you mean through the app you're making?

Comment: Ah, hehe. I'm sorry, but I cannot help you with that. Sorry!

Comment: No Problem. thanks for cooperation :)

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan, maybe you should edit your question to make it clear you want to do this programmatically through the Facebook API. Maybe that's why some people (not me) down voted and asked to close as off topic.

Comment: @Clafou, thanks for response, yes i meant it the way you understood. I have edited the question. Do you know anything about it