# Making an overlay for profile picture on FB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

TL;DR: look for bold text to see the questions without context.

When something bad (or good, but this is a cruel world) happens, FB has a feature to change your profile picture - when USA legalized gay marriage you could have had a rainbow flag over your pic, when SW7 came out, you could have added a lightsaber, etc.

I wanted to do something similiar for a social campaign and started writing an app for that. I figured it should be possible, as in case of Star Wars it seemed to be managed by private company (Disney), not FB itself.

My plan was to:

1. download current user profile pic (done, though I cannot get good quality; anyway, gonna fix that later)
2. in-memory add the banner (done)
3. upload that photo with banner added (done)
4. redirect user to photo from (3) with makeprofile=1 as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306786/how-to-set-a-facebook-profile-picture-using-the-graph-api), to make it users profile picture
5. profit

Unfortunately, the answer quoted in (4) doesn't seem to be working anymore.

My question is: **is this still possible? If yes - how?
If not - do I have any alternatives?**

I've also tried figuring out how is the link "Make Profile Picture" in webview composed. It looks like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=<<picture id>&set=a.<<similiar, but not the same as picture id>>.<<not a clue>>.<<seems to be profile id>>&type=3&makeprofile=1&profile_id=<<profile id, duh>>&pp_source=photo_view
```

**If anyone knows what following parts mean, my issue would probably be solved**:

- `<<similiar, but not the same as picture id>>`
- `<<not a clue>>`
- `<<seems to be profile id>>`

I also tried figuring out [ProfilePictureSource](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/), but the abstraction itself isn't described anywhere (or I couldn't find it) and judging by permissions needed, that doesn't seem like what I need (why would I need any pages, groups, mailbox or business permissions when I only want to update a profile pic?). **If that is the way and I just lost it, please tell me how to use it.**

**Another way to answer this question would be to propose alternative way of having the banner over profile picture.**

For the record, I'm using Python with [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk) wrapper, but only for fast prototyping - I could as well use Java with Spring Social, DLang with manual HTTP calls, whatever - technology isn't an issue, I need a general way here.

Comment: What you saw (Star Wars/Disney) was most likely the Profile Picture Frames feature, https://www.facebook.com/help/1476775522631878 This is not done via a 3rd-party app/the API, but a feature that Facebook offers for certain pages.