# Set the profile picture for a test user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It looks like it's not possible to programmatically set a user's profile picture - [you can only upload to an album, then send the user to a "make profile picture" page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2995397/1282635). Is there any way to do this for a test user?

I'm doing automated testing for a mobile app and want to generate new test users for each test. However, the app requires users to have a profile picture in order to log in, so it's currently not possible for me to create new users on the fly and have them be able to use the app. Is there a workaround for this? And are there plans for this functionality to be implemented?

(I'm using ruby and httparty to communicate with the API.)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can set up test user's detail from dashboard, but still facebook does not allow to do it programmatically via api.